# Access VR headset orientation in Three.js

Tags: three.js, webxr

How can I access the VR headset orientation in Three.js? The WebXRManager doesn't seem to provide a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the orientation from the camera used for rendering the scene. Try the following when presenting:

```js
const position = new THREE.Vector3();
const rotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
const scale = new THREE.Vector3();

// the following line extracts the position, rotation and scale in world space

camera.matrixWorld.decompose( position, rotation, scale );
```

Comment: Thank you! Someone on the Three.js Discord server helped me find this solution, which also works: 
`let xrCamera; if (renderer.xr.isPresenting === true) { const cameraVector = new THREE.Vector3(); xrCamera = renderer.xr.getCamera(camera); xrCamera.getWorldDirection(cameraVector); }`

Comment: I'm surprised that `getWorldDirection()` works since it force a recomputation of the camera's world matrix which then leads to a known bug: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18448

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe because I'm doing it for each frame in the animation loop? I'm struggling to find much information about accessing this kind of headset data in Three.js. The documentation doesn't offer much help and seems to be incomplete. For example, I still can't figure out how to find the headset's height above the floor.

Comment: Can't you just extract the `y` component from the above `position` vector?

Comment: The camera is part of a "user" rig, so the `y` component changes with the user object's position. I want to access the floor height of the device so that the user doesn't go through the floor. Also, the rotation value returned by your method is not the same as rotation returned by the method I mentioned above, and the value from your method doesn't work in my flight controls. I'd like to open-source these first-person controls so that others don't have to go through what I'm going through. If you'd be willing to take a look and give me some pointers, I can send you a link.

Comment: I'm building on an existing Three.js example, so maybe this could eventually be included along with the other VR examples, or someone could build on what I'm making and include that. First-person controls are a must for VR, so it would be great to provide people with something that works.

Comment: I was able to get your method to work by not calling `xrCamera = renderer.xr.getCamera(camera);`. Working with VR is very confusing right now in Three.js. I see you have a pull request open that would make this behavior less confusing, though.